# I need what others methods can run only after i push any button in dialog

Tags: android, dialog

I've got dialog method after him other methods.
I need what others methods can run only after i push any button in dialog.

Now when I run dialog at once other methods run too ((

not method in

```
    ... 
    builder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            method1();
            method2();
        }
    });
    ...
```

Other metoh i don't want put in builder.setPositiveButton onClick.
because then i've got a lot of program.

```
        dialog();

        DataBase playersDataBase = new DataBase(this);
        playersDataBase.open();
        playersDataBase.ReadDB();

        playersDataBase.checkPlayer(playerName, playerScore);
        playersDataBase.justReadDB();
        playersDataBase.close();
```

All my program run after dialog and don't wait when I put button (( Like myTimer and lot of other methods.

Answer (score 1):

Then you can do it like this:

```
public void showDialogMethod(){

    dialog.show();
    method1();
    method2();

}
```

Call this method when you need to show dialog.

Comment: @user1919362, I am not understanding the question properly. Do you want to run methods on dialog's button click?